# How can I define a subdomain routing in CodeIgniter for a project in Laravel inside the first one?

Tags: laravel, codeigniter, laravel-5, routes, subdomain

Let me explain myself better. I have a website created with CodeIgniter and I am trying to add another project created in Laravel that I want to be accessible by subdomain.

How can I proceed about this? How can I establish the subdomain routing in CodeIgniter to be able to point to the Laravel project?

Comment: If I understood correctly what you want to do, this is something best implemented at the server (Apache/nginx) level rather than at the application level. You could have both "sites" (example.com and laravel.example.com) live in two different directories and have eacg directory act as web root for its domain. By doing that, you save yourself from messing with routes on either or both frameworks, which can get very messy very quickly

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to do with Laravel or CodeIgniter routing,

If you set the Laravel app in subdomain, just call the url to that domain from CodeIgniter.